# Storing encryption keys safely on android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am currently using

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionPassword, salt, 100000);
```

To get a encryption key that is secure and usable but the encryptionPassword can be accessed from a decompiled copy of my .apk.  I am using Unity3D so I don't have access to the android Keystore feature and I don't want to bother setting up a client-server setup because this is a simple game. **Does anyone have a way to generate an encryption password that gives the same password every time but is different per device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could generate the keys with the mac-address of the android device? Maybe generate one .apk file per user?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I was just looking around and found something about the IMEI and mac-address of android devices

Comment: Great, I know IMEI is diffrent per mobile device. But it also can be spoofed I heard once. Don't know how difficult that is..